How do I show a list of "related" pages within a Docusaurus page?
I'm porting my documentation from Jekyll to Docusaurus and am in the process of "refactoring" various Liquid code to Docusaurus/React code.  I have a list of pages where some pages are related to the other and there is a requirement to have these pages link to one another.
The way I do this in Liquid is:
<ul>
  {% assign filterPages = site.pages | where: "categories", include: include.categoryName %}
  {% for doc in filteredPages %}
    {% if doc.randomVar == include.searchValue %}
      <li><a href="{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a> {{ doc.summary }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>


Where:

include.categoryName is a parameter of the category name
doc.randomVar is a frontmatter YAML property randomVar, which (for the purposes of this example) is a string
include.searchValue is a parameter of what to search for within each pages' frontmatter randomVar property value.

I've gone about trying to recreate this several different ways:

Trying to parse frontmatter across all pages: There doesn't seem to be an Object (like pages) that holds all of the page information along with their frontmatter and other meta data.
Using useGlobalData: suffers the same issue as sidebars
Using DocCardList: Only shows child pages within the directory; I need it to show selected pages, some that are children, but also others that are outside the immediate directory.

I may be overthinking this and I'm hoping there is a better way to do what I'm suggesting.  I'm at the point of generating a JSON file at build time and then writing a component to parse that JSON file to build the links.
My preferred end-state is that I can feed a list of pages to DocCardList (using the items parameter -- I tried a version of this but seems that DocCardList is expecting a specific variable type that I'm not sure how to create.  The documentation on this seems very sparse.)
I'll settle for a bullet list of pages with links along with the summary as shown in the Liquid code.
Any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
